# How to get old bash tab completion rules back - stopping before next subdirectory

Tags: bash, rules

Could anyone please confirm to me whether tab completion rules e.g. in Debian/Devuan/Ubuntu Linux have changed some time ago - and how (or from which debian package revision) I could quickly get the old behaviour back?

Details:

I have the impression that tab completion in bash has changed:

- Old: completion always stopped at the next slash (i.e. before entering the next subdirectory):

`cd /m<tab>` would produce: `cd /mnt/` and stop there. Always.

- New: completion proceeds as far down into the path as possible, adding all characters that are identical for all files or further subdirs currently contained in the next subdirectory.

`cd /m<tab>` would produce: `cd /mnt/sd`
on a machine where `/mnt/` contained only `sdb, sdc`

but would produce: `cd /mnt/s`
on a machine where `/mnt/` contained `sdb, sr0`

but would produce: `cd /mnt/`
on a machine where `/mnt/` contained `sdb, fda`

[These path names are merely simple examples. I know UUIDs - different story, that would infer even less predictability anyway.]

The new behaviour is annoying, because at which position it stops for new user input, depends on the (variable) content of the following subdir(s).

For example, to mount something to `/mnt/sdb1`,
I might have to type:

`... /m<tab>1` on one machine, but

`... /m<tab>b1` on another, or

`... /m<tab>sdb1` on yet another.

And to know how far autocompletion took me, and *what* I had to type next, I would have to look at the screen *after each and every usage of* `<tab>`.

Sorry, that's plainly unusable.

In the old behaviour, I could compose long pathnames by invariably beginning with the *first* n character(s) of desired names (which I know) at each new directory level. This worked very fast and *completely without looking* at the screen - completely independent  of the actual contents of the next subdir.

Breaks would only occur, when the number of chars I typed were insufficient for the next `<tab>`; the beep would tell me, and I could simply add another char still without looking - or check what's available with another `<tab>`.

The new behaviour, however, may add zero, or one, or more characters after the next slash - or even advance straight through one or more additional subdirectory levels - completely depending on the files available down there. - So after each and every `<tab>`: *nobody* would know in advance how far it would take them, and where they would have to continue typing the desired path name - without looking at the screen first.

This new behaviour completely breaks any blind-typing-workflow. I cannot compose (even completely known!) pathnames fast with autocompletion any more - without constantly checking back how far it took me and figuring out which character to type next. - This turns autocompletion from a reliable speedup into a hindrance.

Btw., from the theoretical side: To get somewhere fast,...

...the old behaviour needed you to know where you wanted to go. And would get you there fast and reliably by typing a completely foreseeable character sequence.

...the new behaviour needs you to know where you want to go - but also, everything else that might be around (because that influences how far the next `<tab>` will take you). - That's *impossible* (sic!). Therefore, it requires you to check how far you got after each `<tab>`, and *only therafter* to figure out which character to type next to continue. - Brrr.

I assume the "maximum possible" completion was meant as an "improvement" or even labeled "more intelligent".

But as usual in recent years, this "improvement" achieves the opposite - by replacing simple deterministic behaviour by one that can't be mechanically used - without constantly checking and processing screen output first.

I've already read other autocompletion related postings and might look at the rules below

```
/etc/bash_completion*
```

Before trying that, I'd be grateful for a confirmation that there really *was* a change; and even more for a simple notion about when (or why) that happened. I would then try whether the installation of some older bash_completion package might correct the problem.

I'd be even happier if my consideration regarding the usability of both approaches could be carefully reviewed, and the old rules re-established as default shipping behaviour.

Sorry for the lengthy description. I wanted to ensure that even the makers of the new autocompletion rules might understand the problem.

Thanks for consideration and for any hint in advance - Joerg

Comment: Serverfault is for questions about server management, not general computer usage. The [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [superuser](https://superuser.com) are much better places to ask about things like this.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Don't you look at your screen while typing?

Comment: No, I don't want to always have to look.

I'm typing really fast, know the beginning of the needed string and expect bash-completion to provide the rest. Nothing less and nothing more - because I continue typing *before* my brain even comprehends the output of bash-completion.

The new bash-completion rules regularly block me requiring corrections. This is NOT bash-completion searching for what suits my input, but me searching for what would have suited bash-completion's excess output. I'd prefer the old way any day. Especially for servers :-)